# Do half-iterate functions exist for any function?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition, directed-graphs

For a given a deterministic unary function,
$$ f(x) = y $$
A half-iterate function g(x) for f(x) is one which satisfies the following:
$$ g(g(x)) = f(x) $$
For any f(x), does there exist a corresponding g(x) that is a half-iterate for f(x)?

It seems as though this must be true though I am having difficulty proving it. 
Given that any deterministic unary function can be transformed into a directed graph (where $ \overrightarrow {ab} $ denotes the edge pointing from a to b):

$$ \forall \ \overrightarrow  {ab} \in G, \ \ make \ \ f(a) = b$$

And likewise that any graph whose nodes have out-degree of exactly one can be transformed into a unary function -

$$ \forall \ f(a) = b, \ add\  \overrightarrow  {ab} \ to \ G $$

It seems obvious that one could create g(x) by replacing each edge $ \overrightarrow {ab} $ with two others and a third node: $ \overrightarrow {ac} $ and $ \overrightarrow {cb} $. Inserting these two in place of the original edge does not change the important properties of the graph: all the original nodes maintain their same in and out degrees and the new node $c$ has out degree of exactly one.

Is this correct or am I missing an important step?

Comment: Turning functions into graphs is all well and good, but if you don't have a way of unambiguously turning a graph into a function, I don't know how your argument is going to proceed.

Comment: recommend https://books.google.com/books/about/Iterative_Functional_Equations.html?id=IM7cdgtodqUC

Comment: Relevant MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/231934/69658

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your reply - I have just got into the topic and have heard that book is a good start so I will certainly look into it. I'm not clear on why the second conversion (constrained graph to function) is ambiguous, however - could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a vertex in the graph, you're changing the domain of the function. An analogous manipulation without the graph would be to take a function $f : X \to X$ and define a function
$$
   g : X \times \{0,1\} \to X \times \{0,1\}
$$
with $g(x,0) = (x,1)$ and $g(x,1) = (f(x),0)$. Then the composition $g \circ g$ is a function very similar to $f$: we have $g(g(x,y)) = (f(x), y)$ for any $x \in X$ and $y \in \{0,1\}$.

In other words, $g\circ g$ acts the same as $f$ on $X \times\{0\}$ and on $X \times\{1\}$: on both copies of $X$ inside its domain. But it is not the same function as $f$.